# Turning NDWI values into percentage from -1 to 1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, normalized-difference-water-index

The usual values of NDWI come as -1 to 1 but I want to show these values as 0-100%.

How do I do that using the Raster Calculator of ArcMap?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
(1 + "mndwi") * 50
```

[image]